# Decompose $\frac{x^2 - x - 4}{x(x + 2)^2}$ into partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

How do I equate coefficients when decomposing the following expression into partial fractions? $$\frac{x^2 - x - 4}{x(x + 2)^2}$$

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: According to the textbook the partial fraction form is A/x + B/(x +2) + C/(x + 2)^2 = x^2 - x - 4. Then you multiply both sides by x(x + 2)^2, you get A(x +2)^2 + Bx(x + 2) + Cx = x^2 - x - 4. Is this correct so far? From here I understand you need to replace x with -2 to get C = -1. but from here I'm stuck, how do I determine A and B???

Comment: Yes, what you have done so far is correct. What is generally done then is comparing coefficients: The coefficient of $x^2$ on the LHS is $A+B$, the coefficient of $x$ is $4A+2B+C$ and the coefficient of $x^0$ is $4A$ on the RHS you get, respectively, the coefficients $1$ for $x^2,$ $-1$ for $x$ and $-4$ for $x^0$. This gives you a system of linear equations:$$ \begin{align}A+B&=&1\\4A+2B+C&=&-1\\4A&=&-4\end{align}$$

Comment: How do you know that A + B = 1? Where do you get the 4 of 4A and the 2 of 2B and how do you know 4A + 2B + C = -1?

Comment: $$\begin{align} A(x+2)^2+Bx(x+2)+Cx&=Ax^2+4Ax+4A+Bx^2+2Bx+Cx\\&=(A+B)x^2+(4A+2B+C)x+4A\\&=x^2-x-4 \end{align}$$Therefore, $$\begin{align} A+B&=&1\\4A+2B+C&=&-1\\4A&=&-4\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x^2-x-4}{x(x+2)^2}=\frac A{x}+\frac B{x+2}+\frac C{(x+2)^2}\implies$$

$$x^2-x-4=A(x+2)^2+Bx(x+2)+Cx$$

The above is a polynomial equality, so you can either compare coefficients of respective powers of $\,x\,$ in both sides and/or substitute some values of $\,x\,$ in both sides. For example

$$x=0\implies -4=4A\implies A=-1\\x=-2\implies 2=-2C\implies C=-1$$

$$\text{Coefficients of }\;x^2:\implies 1=A+B\implies B=2$$

and we're done...

Comment: But how do you know x=0? are you using random numbers? cause it feels like it?

Comment: How can x = 0 and x = -2 ?

Comment: Those are *substitutions*, @user91144: $\;x\;$ is **not** a constant value, but an unknonw or variable which can attain several values. So what happens if $\;x=0\;$ ? So and so. And now what happens with $\,x=-2\,$ ? Etc.